# Convert Decimal Cent to String Euros

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I have the following string conversion for a decimal number:

```
String.Format("€ {0:0.00}", 4610.00)
```

but that gives me 4610.00 when in actual fact i need 46,10 (the given decimal is in cents)

I've tried a few variations of the string formatter but so far can't get the euro value for the given cents, would i just have to divide by 100 and then format it or is there a better way?

How do i convert it so i get the euro representation of the cents and not a direct format of the given decimal?

Comment: This has little to do with formatting. You have cents, you want euro's. Divide by 100. Then format.

Comment: You need to convert 4610 cents to Euro? How does .net know the conversion rate between Euro and cents? You manually need to do conversion using formula like `var euros = 4610/100;` and then display euros in whatever format you want.

Comment: That's a decimal representation of a non-decimal number. Use `decimal` datatype to ensure that you don't get bitten by floats.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a calculation. `String.Format` is only for formating strings and not to change cents into euros.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("€ {0:0.00}", 4610.00m / 100));
```

> € 46.10

Comment: For the love of all that is good : `4610.00M` please. Currency and IEEE floating point representations don't mix. Use the `decimal` data-type for currency.